# How to completely disable/rewrite HTTPS in default nginx server?

Tags: ssl, nginx

I don't have certificate for main domain so I use self-singed cert for my several dev-domains.

I use it like this:

```
server {
    listen       443;
    server_name  secure.somehost.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/secure.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/secure.key;
}
server {
    listen         80;
    server_name    secure.somehost.com;
    rewrite        ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

Now all my https requests (ex. `https://anyhost.somehost.com/`) are somehow rewritten to `https://secure.somehost.com`. So I want to disable this behaviour and turn off HTTPS for default server and ideally send rewrite to simple HTTP (or simply send 500 error).

I've tried this code. But since I don't have certificate I guess I can't send proper response.

```
server {
    listen 443 default;
    rewrite ^(.*) http://$host$1 permanent;
}
```

I have to use `default` server because I handle a lot of subdomains and external domains as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect an `https` request (on port 443) to `http` (on port 80), you should include the SSL certificate and key directives in the server block, like this:

```
# redirect all default http requests to http://example.com
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    access_log off;
    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}

# redirect all https requests to http://example.com
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name _;

    # ssl certificate and private key
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/secure.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/secure.key;

    # you can add additional ssl parameters here (like the protocols
    # and ciphers you want nginx to use).

    return 301 http://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Just change the redirect's destination URL to the default domain/subdomain you want to use.

If you are using a self-signed certificate, the browser will still prompt you and say the certificate is untrusted. Once you add it as an exception in your browser's cache the connection should work without the browser stopping to flag it as untrusted every time.

Comment: The thing is I can't use self-signed certificate for main domain because I don't want users to see browser warning message. Also I deal with a lot of domains so I really can't really produce certificates for all of them. I just want https off.

Comment: You can just omit the server blocks for 443. Nginx only listens to ports you define in your config. If you do not have server blocks for 443, nginx won't use that port. But if your users go to ``https:``// ... your-domain they will not reach anything (the browser will probably say they can't find that domain). If you *do* need to redirect 443 to 80, you will need at least one ssl certificate (from a CA and not self-signed) so you can redirect the requests without warning.

Comment: What can I do if I need one server block with 443 for specific subdomain? Maybe there is any solution?

Comment: For any 443 connections, you will need a certificate from the CA to avoid the browser warning. So you would need to define just the server block you need for the subdomain, and have that block be listening on port 443 with ssl on.